# Drag and Drop in UICollectionView that has UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview

I'm having UICollectionView that scrolls horizontally. Each collection view cell has a table view that scrolls vertically. I want to implement drag and drop of table view cell with in the table view itself as well as between different tableviews within each collection view cell. 
Need some tutorial or help to achieve the functionality.

Comment: You mean like Trello ios application ?

Comment: @karthik, Exactly same behavior as in Trello app. Any ideas?

Comment: you can go for uipagecontroller, instead of collection view. trello handling the same. will give you , If I have any.

Comment: @Satyam have you done this design? I need your help

Comment: @Jason, Sorry I couldn't achieve it.

Comment: @satyam have you any demo related to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try these tutorials

https://www.raywenderlich.com/63089/cookbook-moving-table-view-cells-with-a-long-press-gesture
http://www.freshconsulting.com/create-drag-and-drop-uitableview-swift/
http://www.andypierz.com/blog/2014/11/9/basic-drag-and-drop-uitableviews-using-swift-and-core-data

http://www.iostute.com/2016/02/how-to-re-order-table-view-cell-by-drag.html

Some helpful Libraries

```
https://github.com/andreamazz/UIView-draggable
https://github.com/ra1028/RACollectionViewReorderableTripletLayout
https://github.com/lukescott/DraggableCollectionView
https://github.com/grillbiff/DragAndDropTableView
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info. I've gone through all those tutorials before posting this question. I want drag and drop across table views that are part of collection view cells.

Answer (score 0):

@Satyam, it may help you to get some idea. trello ios application has their own lib to get those behaviour.

```
-> uiViewController    
 -> uiScrollView
   -> uiPageViewController
     -> uiTableViewController
       -> drag and drop behaviour. while dragging, scrollview helps you to get the moving behaviour.
```

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/icarousel

Comment: The complexity is in identifying the long press in table view and navigate it across multiple tableviews through scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

Quickly whipped up a test project, and as far as I've tested, it works fine.

https://github.com/BridgeTheGap/Trelloesque

The secret is the following two methods:

```
func convertPointToIndexPath(point: CGPoint) -> (UITableView, NSIndexPath)? {
    if let tableView = [tableView1, tableView2, tableView3].filter({ $0.frame.contains(point) }).first {
        let localPoint = scrollView.convertPoint(point, toView: tableView)
        let lastRowIndex = focus?.0 === tableView ? tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0) - 1 : tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0)
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(localPoint) ?? NSIndexPath(forRow: lastRowIndex, inSection: 0)
        return (tableView, indexPath)
    }

    return nil
}
```

While not exactly the same, I think it has enough for you to work on.

- Disclaimer: didn't have time to test it, so may be bug-prone.

Comment: have you Objective c version of Trelloesque?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Also there are some bugs I've found.